# Passing credentials to service stack rest api through angularJs and $http.get

Tags: api, security, angularjs, http-headers, servicestack

I have a service stack web service with the CorsFeature enabled.

I am calling a service through AngularJS's $http.get method with the setting withCredentials to true:

```
$http.get(url,{ withCredentials: true})
```

How do I securely pass the credentials to be used by the rest api?

Comment: Hi Daniel did you get this working?

Comment: hi Scott, still looking into it at present, (its a side project), thank you for all the information though, will post my solution when I have it.

Answer (score 4):

On the ServiceStack side you must set your `CorsFeature` plugin to have `allowCredentials = true` and set a single origin. *You can't have an origin of * when using `allowCredentials`.*

`withCredentials` basically allows your origin domain and the ServiceStack service endpoint to share cookies, and pass the [`Authorization` HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), (when CORS is correctly configured). So ultimately your credentials could be a session cookie or an `Authorization` HTTP header.

This [Mozilla documentation about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials) is good at explaining how the cross domain `withCredentials` works.

Because the CORS feature and `withCredentials` only sets up the ability for the domains to share cookies and pass the `Authorization` header, and doesn't do the authentication - you will need to find a suitable authentication mechanism.

You can either build your own authentication mechanism, or consider implementing the ServiceStack Authentication provider, which you can [read about it here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization). Essentially you would want to do a post to:

```
POST server:port/auth/credentials?format=json

{
    "UserName": "admin",
    "Password": "test"
    "RememberMe": true
}
```

The authentication service would pass back a session cookie, and when you use `withCredentials` in your later requests, the cookie will be included automatically, and thus your request will authenticate.

To address passing the credentials securely, you will want to use HTTPS to avoid exposing the credentials in transit. This means securing the username and password value, as well as the session token value.

[image: Process]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have a basic authentication mechanism setup within service stack. When I call an endpoint through the restConsole app I am asked to authenticate and I can see the credentials I enter within fiddler as an authorization cookie. The credentials are hardcoded, they are for me to use to access an external service stack api. So if I create an Authorization cookie somehow, how does this get passed every time I use the AngularJS $http get method?

Comment: @DanielBillingham You need to call your authentication method, from AngularJS, the server side authentication should be creating the session cookie, (not the clientside), and send it to your client in it's response. Then when you  send subsequent requests using AngularJS $http get with the `withCredential` flag the session cookie would be sent too. While you can use JavaScript to create the cookie on the client side, I am not sure a manually created cookie will work cross domain - I would have to verify that.

Comment: @DanielBillingham I have added a diagram to illustrate how it's supposed to work. Essentially you must authenticate against the service. This will set a cookie on your client. Any request you make thereafter to your service, where you add `withCredentials`, the cookie will get sent with the request. The server can then see the cookie when processing the request and decide if you are authenticated.